# strtr и цикл while - удалить все вхождения, а не только последнее

Tags: php

У нас есть цикл:

```
$i = 0;
while($count>$i) {
$bvc = trim($slovo[$i]);
$trans = array($bvc => ' ');
$chist = strtr($tova, $trans);
$i++;
}
echo $chist;
```

Нам нужно вывести данные из переменной $chist, где должны быть удалены все вхождения. Сейчас удаляется по одному вхождению - последнему.

Скрипт полностью (с исправления от KiTE, не работает):

```
$trr = '<div class="category"><a href="#" rel="tag" title="">продукция</a>
<a href="#" rel="tag" title="">хозяйство</a>
<a href="#" rel="tag" title="">хранение</a></div>';
$sttr = $trr.'<div class="actions_tags"><a href='#'>продукция</a>, <a href='#'>хранение</a></div>';
preg_match('|<div class="category">(.*)</div>|Uis', $sttr, $p_category);
preg_match('|<div class="actions_tags">(.*)</div>|Uis', $sttr, $p_keywords);
$p_keywords[1] = strip_tags($p_keywords[1]);
$p_category[1] = strip_tags($p_category[1]);
$explode = explode(",", $p_keywords[1]);
$exp_count = count($explode);
$ing = 0;
//Начало исправления KiTE
$chist = '';
while($exp_count>$ing) {
$bvc = trim($explode[$ing]);
$trans = array($bvc => ' ');
$chist .= strtr($p_category[1], $trans);
$ing++;
}
echo $chist;
//Конец
```

Содержание $trr и $sttr постоянно меняется.

Comment: зачем мучать код и себя, используйте for, а с решением вопроса, надо подумать

    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
    {
    $bvc = trim($slovo[$i]);
    $trans = array($bvc => ' ');
    $chist = strtr($tova, $trans);
    }

Comment: oxyage, я привык использовать while, про for знаю, но все равно, спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$i = 0;
$chist = '';
while($count>$i) {
$bvc = trim($slovo[$i]);
$trans = array($bvc => ' ');
$chist .= strtr($tova, $trans);
$i++;
}
echo $chist;
```

Comment: Выводится $i раз содержание $tova, т.е. выводится $i раз содержание без всяческих замен.

Comment: Значит проблема где-то в другом участке кода. Вопрос звучит "Как собрать данные из каждой итерации цикла в одну переменную". Я именно на него и ответил. 2-я строка делает предварительную очистку переменной `$chist`, а 6-я - добавляет в конец этой переменной результат от `strtr($tova, $trans)` в каждой итерации цикла.

Для отладки своего кода рекомендую поставить `echo strtr($tova, $trans);` внутри цикла. Чтобы ты видел что эта функци

Comment: Показал скрипт полностью, он очень маленький, вывод strt ничего не дал - выдается одно и то же.