# Удалить из переменной $p_category совпадения данных с переменной $p_keywords

Tags: php

У нас есть скрипт:

```
$trr = '<div class="category"><a href="#" rel="tag" title="">продукция</a>
<a href="#" rel="tag" title="">хозяйство</a>
<a href="#" rel="tag" title="">хранение</a></div>';
$sttr = $trr.'<div class="actions_tags"><a href='#'>продукция</a>, <a href='#'>хранение</a></div>';
preg_match('|<div class="category">(.*)</div>|Uis', $sttr, $p_category);
preg_match('|<div class="actions_tags">(.*)</div>|Uis', $sttr, $p_keywords);
$p_keywords[1] = strip_tags($p_keywords[1]);
$p_category[1] = strip_tags($p_category[1]);
```

Список слов в переменной $sttr всегда перечисляется через запятую, содержание меняется.
Нам нужно удалить совпадения данных переменной из $p_category с переменной $p_keywords.

Т.е. если в переменной $p_category у нас были данные "Привет, как дела, скоро выйдет этот фильм, не знаешь?", а в переменной $p_keywords были данные "как дела, не знаешь", то в итоге должен получиться результат "Привет,, скоро выйдет этот фильм?" при этом удаление/не удаление этих запятых не принципиально.

Как это реализовать?
Связанный вопрос: [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/71054/strtr-%D0%B8-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB-while-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну для этого надо использовать PHP-функцию, вычисляющую расхождение в массивах -

> `array_diff(array $array1,array $array2[, array ...])`

Она возвращает массив, состоящий из значений массива **$array1**, которые отсутствуют в любом другом массиве, перечисленном в последующих аргументах. Как использовать её в твоем случае - это уже ты и сам способен догодаться =)

Answer (score 1):

[explode](http://ua.php.net/explode) + [array_intersect](http://ua.php.net/array_intersect)